# Getting layout parameters from the geometry package

Tags: margins, geometry

The `geometry` package provides a simple way to set layout parameters. For example,

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

will give me a document with 1 inch margins on each side. In particular, it computes the LaTeX parameters like `\textwidth`, `\oddsidemargin`, `\textheight`, and `\topmargin`, among others. Is it possible to retrieve the 'friendlier' values like `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom`?

Of course, one can compute the values using something like `\dimexpr \topmargin + \headheight + \headsep + 1in \relax`. There's also the further complication that the `includehead` and `includefoot` options influence the setting of the parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The values are stored in pt in commands like `\Gm@lmargin`, `\Gm@tmargin` etc. If you are interested in the unit you actually used in the options you could also patch `\Gm@defbylen` which is (as far as I can see) used by most options and then set the values with `\geometry`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\makeatletter
\def\Gm@defbylen#1#2{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname myGm#1\endcsname{#2}%new
  \begingroup\setlength\@tempdima{#2}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname Gm@#1\endcsname{\the\@tempdima}\endgroup}%

\geometry{margin=1in}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter\Gm@lmargin \myGmlmargin

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The command`\geometryget` takes a single mandatory argument, which should be the name of one of `geometry` package's optional parameters, e.g. `left`, `top`, `textheight`, etc. (the version below supports only the parameters `lmargin`, `rmargin`, `tmargin`, and `bmargin`, and their various aliases, but it can be readily extended to include all of `geometry`'s optional parameters).

It expands to the value of the corresponding parameter, in units of `pt`s.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/geometry/lmargin}{lmargin}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/geometry/left}{lmargin}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/geometry/inner}{lmargin}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/geometry/innermargin}{lmargin}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/geometry/rmargin}{rmargin}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/geometry/right}{rmargin}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/geometry/outer}{rmargin}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/geometry/outermargin}{rmargin}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/geometry/tmargin}{tmargin}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/geometry/top}{tmargin}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/geometry/bmargin}{bmargin}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/geometry/bottom}{bmargin}

\newcommand{\geometryget}[1]
   {\csname Gm@\pgfkeysvalueof{/geometry/#1}\endcsname}

\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|ll|ll|ll|ll|}
lmargin&\geometryget{lmargin}&
rmargin&\geometryget{rmargin}&
tmargin&\geometryget{tmargin}&
bmargin&\geometryget{bmargin}\\
left&\geometryget{left}&
outer&\geometryget{outer}&
top&\geometryget{top}&
bottom&\geometryget{bottom}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Retrieving the values of package geometry's optional parameters]

---

A more substantial example of usage.

The following example uses `\geometryget` to set the width of the margin notes to .8 of the width of the right margin and to center them in the right margin.

In the code above insert the following to the preamble after the loading of the `geometry` package.

```
\geometry{hscale=.66,hmarginratio=1:4}

\usepackage{pgfmath}
\pgfmathsetlength{\marginparsep}{.1*\geometryget{right}}
\pgfmathsetlength{\marginparwidth}{.8*\geometryget{right}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
```

Replace the document's body with the following:

```
\lipsum[1-1]
\marginpar{\lipsum[2-2][1-1]}

\lipsum[3-7]
```

[image: Using \geometryget to set the width of the margin notes relative to the width of the right margin]