# Package geometry parameters and changing left margin

Tags: margins, indentation, geometry

I want to make an indented paragraph, that is to indent the whole paragraph and not just the first line as happens with `\par`. I use `geometry`, so I thought that package might have a parameter that regulates the indent. I read through the `.log` file of my document and found:

```
\Gm@cnth=\count186
\Gm@cntv=\count187
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count188
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen277
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen278
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen279
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen280
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen281
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen282
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen283
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen284
\Gm@dimlist=\toks36
```

Seeing as I couldn't guess what these were, I came here. I looked at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44846/default-margins-for-geometry-package) and [this other one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7829/getting-layout-parameters-from-the-geometry-package), so I found `\hoffset`, but opening a group and changing that seemed to have no effect. Same goes for `\Gm@layouthoffset`. Typing:

```
{\makeatletter\Gm@lmargin=2pt
foo bar baz
\makeatother \\
}
```

with a `\\` just before the `{` makes the `foo bar baz` typeset, but instead of changing the parameter prints out `113.81102pt=2pt`. So the question is: what are those parameters, how do I use them, can I use them to indent the paragraph as I want, and if not how do I?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35933/indenting-a-whole-paragraph/ or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36121/write-text-with-some-fixed-amount-of-space-from-the-margin/ is perhaps helpful.

Comment: `geometry` can change the margin for a page or pages but not for a single paragraph. Either use something like `chngpage` to adjust the width temporarily or use a customised itemize environment. For example, you could use `enumitem` to achieve this kind of effect.

Comment: Typographically it may be most relevant to use a `quote` or `quotation` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `geometry` is surely not what you're looking for. The pagination parameters are relevant only when the page is shipped out, the only one that's relevant during typesetting is `\textwidth`, but it's better not to tamper with it.

The `changepage` packages provides the `adjustwidth` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{0cm}
\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{1cm}
\lipsum[4]
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might also look at the `quoting` package.

Note that, while setting `\leftskip` may seem to work, it is *not* compatible with lists in the indented material.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}    
\newenvironment{mypar}
  {\par\leftskip=2cm}
  {\par}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{mypar}
\blindtext
\end{mypar}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]